# Getting html source changes dynamically from ifram tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extract

I've been trying to get html source from iframe tag for a while, however, sadly I'm still failing on it. My environment is under chrome browser and with dom-distiller extension that gives me a feature extracting main articles from web pages. This extension worked with the code below.

```
<iframe id="dom-distiller-result-iframe" 
src="chrome-extension://oiembdaoobijmdmeobkalaehgifealpl/external/chromium/src/components/dom_distiller/core/html/dom_distiller_viewer.html" 
style="z-index: 2147483647; position: fixed; 
left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; 
margin: auto; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: white; border: none;">
</iframe>
```

It injected some iframe tag in the web page I'm seeing. With this iframe tag, a distilled document was wonderfully rendered without ADs. I thought if I could access iframe tag whose id is "dom-distiller-result-iframe" and get rendered html source code. I've tried many ways however, none of them didn't worked.

Could any one give me some advices?

Answer (score 0):

Did not test it but should do the job:

```
<?
$url = "yoursite.com";

$html = file_get_html($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$iFrame = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0);
$iFrameID = $iFrame->getAttribute('id');

$iframehtml = file_get_html($iFrameID);

echo $iframehtml;

?>
```

Comment: Javascript is the only option for my case. Thanks anyway. :)